# In JavaFx how is rendering of a scene graph carried out or triggered

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to understand how [Nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) are rendered to the screen in JavaFX and what triggers this process as I want to create a custom control in JavaFx. I have experience of working Android's [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class in which the drawing of a View is different to drawing a scene graph in JavaFX.

For example in Android's I can create a custom `View` and override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. In `onDraw()` this is where I can place all my drawing requirements by drawing directory onto the `Canvas` object. The method is called on the UI thread and once the `onDraw` has completed the canvas is automatically displayed. I can trigger a re-draw of the View at any time by calling the View's `invalidate()` method if on the GUI thread or `postInvalidate()` if not.

In JavaFx, I do not work with a Canvas object but with Node objects instead and there is no equivalent of `onDraw()` as far as I am aware. So if I am creating a custom Control I would extend the [Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) class and also create a class extending [SkinBase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html). The `SkinBase` class is where I create the 'look' of the custom control by creating various Node objects to suit. But then:

1. What do I do with those Node objects to actually get them rendered?
2. What if I need to change some property of one of the nodes e.g. its
   colour?
3. How do I 'invalidate' the Skin to have it re-rendered either
   from the GUI or another thread?

It's apparent that I am trying to draw parallels with how Android's View class works and this is at the risk of confusing how Android and JavaFx rendering processes works but Android is my knowledge starting point.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm).

Comment: Here is a tutorial for creating a custom control: http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

1. Nothing: once the nodes are part of the scene graph, the FX rendering system will render them
2. Again, nothing. JavaFX has an [observable properties API](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). Properties of nodes that affect the appearance are represented by these observable properties. Consequently, if a property changes, the change is observed and the FX rendering system knows to re-render the node on the next rendering pulse.
3. You must do this from the FX Application thread. As in 2., you simply have to change the value of a property and the node (and consequently its ancestor nodes in the scene graph) will automatically be invalidated. Again, changes to nodes that are part of the scene graph *must* happen on the FX Application Thread. You can use [`Platform.runLater(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to schedule code to execute on the FX Application Thread from a background thread (or use the [JavaFX concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand it. I am trying to create a custom control which is made up of several Node objects contained within `SkinBase`, but a `Node` is not observable, so how does the JavaFX GUI thread get informed to a Node has changed of even there? I suppose I am looking for an explanation of what GUI thread is doing in JavaFX. Is it constantly traversing the scene tree looking for changes. I need the equivalent of Andorid's explanation of drawing http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html but for JavaFx.

Comment: @Kerry: IIUC, you may be looking for the [pulse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) mechanism.